# WebGL and GraphicsCriticalError in Selenium / C# on Raspberry Pi with Firefox

Tags: selenium, .net-core, raspberry-pi, geckodriver

I have a Raspberry Pi 3b+. I wrote a .NET Core 5.0 program which uses Selenium to do some tasks on the browser. It all works 100% fine on my Windows PC. But it has errors when ran on the Raspberry Pi running 64 bit Ubuntu Server Focal version. I have the Gecko driver and Firefox installed. The program is able to complete its tasks, but throws many many errors about:

> "Crash Annotation GraphicsCriticalError: |[0][GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server (t=4.70096) [GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server"

> "JavaScript warning: https://js.arcgis.com/3.38/esri/dijit/BasemapGallery.js, line 22: WebGL warning: : WebglAllowWindowsNativeGl:false restricts context creation on this system."
> "* Exhausted GL driver options. (FEATURE_FAILURE_WEBGL_EXHAUSTED_DRIVERS)"
> "JavaScript warning: https://js.arcgis.com/3.38/init.js, line 1171: Failed to create WebGL context: WebGL creation failed:"

I tried installing xvfb but that did nothing. I am running headless and the driver confirms that I am running headless, but seems to be expecting a display regardless????

How do I solve these errors? Note, I do not care if I have to use Firefox, Chromium, or some other browser. But it seemed like Firefox was the most straightforward to install.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I changed operating systems to Raspberry Pi OS 64-bit Lite beta, easily installed Chrome and Chrome Driver... no problems.

I guess the problem was when running Ubuntu, the package repositories had mis-matching versions for arm64 packages and some things installed via 'snap', which is a no-go for programs that have to work together. On the Raspberry OS repository, they had matching versions and no 'snap'.  At least it all works now in case anyone else sees this.